# Unable to push code to a github repository

Tags: git, github

I'm unable to push my changes to a github repository, and get the following error message -

```
D:\Research\scribe-java>git push git@github.com:fernandezpablo85/scribe-java.git master
The authenticity of host 'github.com (207.97.227.239)' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is -----.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
Warning: Permanently added 'github.com,207.97.227.239' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
D:\Research\scribe-java>git push git@github.com:fernandezpablo85/scribe-java.git master
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

Can anybody help me understand what am i doing wrong here...?

Answer (score 2):

Just from that error it looks like your private key is invalid. Have you added your public key to github?

Also: [Github Permission denied](https://help.github.com/articles/error-permission-denied-publickey)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have created your key with super user permissions and now you cannot use it because your are normal user.

Answer (score 0):

first create the ssh key by using

$ssh-keygen -t rsa

The key gets created at ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
copy that key and add to github. may be it will work